# Clear purchase history?

Tags: google-play-store

can the purchase history be cleared? I want to remove my history of purchase so I have no comments with my spouse.
Thank you I haven't found anything yet on the net.

Comment: I dare not ask what apps you wish to hide, although for legal reasons I believe Google retain this info for keeping track of financial information. If you are referring to the Play Store history yes, you can remove the app, but I do not believe you are able to remove Google's records of purchase.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, currently the Google Play Store **does not** support clearing of purchase history.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Google account to the phone and remove the old one. It'll show no purchases were made on the new one.

Comment: Whilst this works, wouldn't his spouse be suspicious that no purchases were made?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I want to support you hiding things from your spouse, but if you log onto google.com/play on a PC and sign into your account there you can permanently delete things from your purchase history, but you also lose the app permanently.